# Computer unable to resume from standby

Tags: windows-xp, standby

My desktop running Windows XP is unable to resume from standby.

When it is in standby mode, if I try to wake it up by pressing a button on the keyboard or by pressing the power button, the fan starts, the HDD LED stays on forever and the screen remains black.

There is no error in the Event Viewer around the time of each standby-wake up

This problem has been there since the birth of my computer. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: First check the event log files. Any failure message on that? If any add that to the post. If none, check the drivers. Are they up to date? Are there know problems with that drivers? How are they configured to act on sleep/suspend? ...

Comment: My guess would be, that there is some device not waking up properly.

Try to get to the root of it, by minimizing your active devices and changing BIOS settings - maybe to not suspend HDD.

Further you should extend your Question by providing your current ACPI configuration.

Comment: @Hennes There is no error in the event viewer around the time of the standby-wake up. There has been no error for the past several day either. The drivers as up to date as far as I know. I don't quite get your last sentence, how do I find that out?

Comment: @Jook How can I make the HDD not suspend? How can I find out my current ACPI config?

Comment: He is asking about the Wakeup/Sleep settings of your BIOS - look into the manual of your Mainboard. However, if this kinda just became an issue over night, my bet would be the HDD.

Comment: I forgot to clarify, this problem has been there since the birth of my computer, and it's not some overnight problem

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907477